# Does all big retailer accept bitcoins?

Tags: retail

Big online Retailer, who accept bitcoin? I am currently looking to buy some product from a giant retailer. I just need the accurate information. Who can help me?

Comment: That giant retailer can help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is extremely stupid

Comment: This *is* hardcore.

Answer (score 1):

No, the first and big retailer that accepts bitcoins was Overstock.com and only for orders inside United States.
Also recently TigerDirect started accepting bitcoin payments for online orders.

Comment: That is not correct anymore: TigerDirect is now also accepting Bitcoins.

Comment: Edited but AFAIK they still don't accept bitcoin payments.

Comment: I read somewhere that they had orders in the value of $270k, within the first 17 hours. So, either I am messing that up with something else or they are already accepting Bitcoin. I am also fairly sure that [TigerDirect's page](http://www.tigerdirect.com/bitcoin/) indicates that you can select *Bitcoin* as payment option.

Comment: I just decided to actually check *for science*. ;) Their homepage (the very first) has a giant Bitcoin themed background and it says "Bitcoin now available on over 200,000 products".

Answer (score 0):

If the giant retailer says that they accept bitcoins as payment, on their website and you can pay for the item you want with bitcoins, there should be no problem.